# Passing a second argument to Guava Cache load() method

Tags: java, caching, dropwizard, google-guava-cache

I've previously asked a question on here on how to implement Guava Cache in Java, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372539/how-do-i-implement-guava-caching-in-dropwizard).  While it has worked, I've recently noticed a bug in the getAllProfile method.

```
private LoadingCache<Integer, List<Profile>> loadingCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .refreshAfterWrite(10,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .maximumSize(100).build(
            new CacheLoader<Integer, List<Profile>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Profile> load(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                    Profile profile= new Profile();
                    if (integer == null) {
                        integer = 10;
                    }
                    return profileDAO.getAllProfiles(profile, integer);
                }
            }
    );

public List<Profile> getAllProfiles(Profile profile, Integer integer) throws Exception {
        return loadingCache.get(integer);
    }
```

In the method, I'm passing in a `Profile` object called `profile`.  This is so that on the Service layer, the user can set a parameter for the profiles of workers, to see if they are still employed, using @QueryParam:

```
@GET
public List<Profile> getProfiles(@QueryParam("employed") Boolean employed, @QueryParam("size") Integer integer) {
//code for service here.  the value for query param is used in a 
//new Profile object
}
```

The profile object created here is passed down through the manager tier, and into the DAO tier, where the parameters set in it, like the boolean employed, are parsed into arguments for a select statement.

The issue here is that since I've started using the cache, the boolean is no longer being parsed.  calling the method with a System.out.println to evaluate the employed field evaluates as null.  This makes sense, as I create a new Profile object in the cache manager, with no setters called, in addition to the cache get method not taking profile at the getAllProfile method; it only takes size.

I thought I could get around this by adding in a new Profile parameter in the load method, like so:

```
private LoadingCache<Integer, List<Profile>> loadingCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .refreshAfterWrite(10,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .maximumSize(100).build(
                new CacheLoader<Integer, List<Profile>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<Profile> load(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                        @Override
                            public List<Profile> load(Integer integer, Profile profile) throws Exception {
                                if (integer == null) {
                                    integer = 10;
                                }
                                return profileDAO.getAllProfiles(profile, integer);
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

However, load() appears to be designed only to take one argument, so this brings up this error:

```
Class 'Anonymous class derived from CacheLoader' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'load(K)' in 'CacheLoader'
```

To reiterate, all I need to do is pass the profile object created in Service layer to the manager layer and cache.  This seems to be as simple as passing a second argument to load(), but that does not seem to be possible.

EDIT:

I've edited the getAllProfiles method to use Callable:

```
public List<Profile> getAllProfiles(Profile profile, Integer integer) throws Exception {
        return loadingCache.get(size, new Callable<Profile>() {
            @Override
            public Profile call() throws Exception {
                return profile;
            }
        });
    }
```

This produces an error on the fact that I'm passing in `Profile` instead of `List<Profile>`.  I need to pass in `profile`, though, so I can parse through the fields in the DAO for the SQL statement.

Comment: Use `Cache.get(key, callable)` instead

Comment: Can you provide a code example on how callable would be used in this?  I'll edit my question to show how I'm using it, but the documentation and examples I've found don't seem particularly useful.  When I try to use it to pass in profile, I receive an error on how I'm passing in a Profile object, when it requires a List<Profile> object.

Comment: Your cached value is `List<Profile>`, so you need to return that. The `profile` is passed through via the anonymous class, which lets you call the `profileDAO.searchProfile(profile)` method you showed above.

Comment: I just realized, that second code with search profile is another cache.  I edit that type back to getAllProfiles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
public class ImageCache2 extends CaffeineCache<URL, Image> {
    ImageCache2() {
        this.cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(300)
                .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .refreshAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build((k) -> null);
    }
}
```

just give build a null return because we don't use it.

```
public static Image LoadImageFromURL(URL url, double w, double h) {
    URLConnection conn;
    Image returnImage;

    try {
        conn = url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)");

    try (InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream()) {
        returnImage = new Image(stream, w, h, true, true);
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return returnImage;
}
```

here is the code I really use to get the item.

```
public static void useExecutors(Runnable run) {
     executorServices.execute(run);
}

public void LoadImage(URL url, double w, double h, Consumer<Image> callWhenFinish) {

        useExecutors(() ->
        {
            Image thumbImage = ImageCacheInstance.Cache().get(url, (u) -> LoadImageFromURL(url, w, h));

            Platform.runLater(() ->
            {
                callWhenFinish.accept(thumbImage);
                System.out.println("ImageLoad >> Finish -- " + this);
            });
        });
}
```

here is where I call the cache get method. PS: useExecutors run it in a background thread